# Using class name instead of xtype

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Is is possible using a class name instead of xtype for lazy instantiation? So I have not to add `Ext.require` before creating objects.

Comment: then ext would need the whole xtype -> class name mapping on first load, that would require too much space.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not but it doesn't matter as you would need `requires` even if it would be possible. Ext class variables are defined only after they are loaded and they are loaded only if they are in `requires`, `views`, `uses`, etc.